# Performance improvements for the Open GL ES code in the CrashLanding sample code?

Tags: iphone, performance, opengl-es

I'm making an iPhone game based on the [CrashLanding sample code](http://www.71squared.co.uk/iPhone/CrashLanding.zip).  The sample code includes some Open GL ES stuff (Texture2D and MyEAGLView).  **What are some ways to improve the performance of this code?**

I'm fine w/ making certain trade-offs to improve the performance... but I don't what these trade-offs might be.  For example perhaps one can simplify and speed-up the code by requiring the image files to have dimensions that are a power of 2, or perhaps square dimensions, or ... ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images will be automatically turned into power of 2 dimensions on devices that need it (pre 3GS for example).

Performance in graphics is a huge subject.  However it usually comes down to batching your primitive calls so as not to make state changes more than necessary.  Google: texture atlas

You can get a long way with that one thing.

-- David